# Are those $\textit{Radon-Nikodym Derivatives}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From Richard Bass' Real Analysis for Graduate Students Version 3.1 p.115:

> $\textbf{Exercise 13.9}$ Suppose $\mu$, $\nu$ and $\rho$ are finite signed measures,$\nu \ll\mu $,and $\rho\ll \nu.$ Here $\nu\ll\mu$ means that $\nu(A)=0$ whenever $\mu(A)=0$ and $A$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra. Prove that $\rho\ll\mu$ and
> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho }{\mathrm{d} \mu}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho }{\mathrm{d} \nu}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu }{\mathrm{d} \mu}$$

In general,we define *Radon-Nikodym Derivative* of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ under the following conditions:$\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure, $\nu $ be a signed measure and $\nu\ll\mu$.But in $\textbf{Exercise 13.9}$, $\mu$, $\nu$ and $\rho$ are finite signed measures,$\nu \ll\mu $,and $\rho\ll \nu,$ the *Radon-Nikodym Derivative* $ \frac{\mathrm{d}\rho }{\mathrm{d} \mu},\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho }{\mathrm{d} \nu}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu }{\mathrm{d} \mu}$ really exist?

Comment: A finite measure is in particular [$\sigma$-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure). Was that the question ?

Comment: @KurtG.In order to ensure the existence of *Radon-Nikodym Derivative* $\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu }{\mathrm{d} \mu},$ at least, we need to require that $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure, $\nu $ be a signed measure and $\nu\ll\mu$ .but in this exercise,  $\mu$ is a finite signed measure that means $\mu$ is out the scope of  $\sigma$-finite measure.In this case,is  there $\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu }{\mathrm{d} \mu}$ ?

Comment: @KurtG.If we remove the "signed" from the exercise, then all $ \frac{\mathrm{d}\rho }{\mathrm{d} \mu},\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho }{\mathrm{d} \nu}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu }{\mathrm{d} \mu}$ really exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong: We can show that $\nu << \mu$ implies $\nu << \mu^+$ and $\nu << \mu^-$. Then (deleted wrong stuff)...

Comment: Why we have $\nu \ll \mu$ implies $\nu \ll \mu^+$ and $\nu << \mu^-$? When $\mu$ is a signed measure ,how can we define the Radon-Nikodym Derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}\nu }{\mathrm{d} \mu}?$

Comment: @Elisa Yeah sorry, I made a mistake. I'm not sure how to define $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ when $\mu$ is signed. I don't think I've ever seen this.

Comment: @Elisa I am also getting doubts now. [This note](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/221/Radon.pdf) dives deeply into these matters. Must look into this book of Bass *if I only had time*.

Comment: Thanks to both of you anyway. @Kurt G You do not have to spend 
time reading the related parts of Bass'book, since the note you provided is more comprehensive about *Radon-Nikodym Derivative* than  Bass's.He only introduced the *Radon-Nikodym Theorem* for  $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite (positive) measure and $\nu$ a finite (positive) measure. What I can't tell is  whether  those are  clerical errors by author.

Comment: @Elisa . As far as I can tell Bass shows the Radon-Nikodym theorem (Thm. ***13.4.***) only for $\sigma$-finite *positive* measures $\nu\ll\mu$. The exercise you are trying to solve lacks therefore a theorem that we could use. Looks like a typo.